# How to use strophe.plugins with backbone and require.js

Tags: backbone.js, xmpp, requirejs, strophe

I use the strophe.archive plugin but the done function of the Deferred object seems to be "undefined" after Strophe sends the query. I also added the plugin to the "shim" of require.js:

```
        var q = $.Deferred();     
        q = connection.archive.listCollections("user@server.lit");
        console.log(q);
        q.done(function(){
            console.log("DONE");
        });
```

I get the following trace:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'done' of undefined test.js:23
Backbone.View.extend.initialize test.js:23
Backbone.View backbone.js:1148
child backbone.js:1393
Backbone.Router.extend.pageTest router.js:92
(anonymous function) backbone.js:900
(anonymous function) backbone.js:1082
_.some._.any underscore.js:193
_.extend.loadUrl backbone.js:1080
_.extend.navigate backbone.js:1125
_.extend.navigate backbone.js:909
Backbone.View.extend.pageTest test1.js:199
jQuery.event.dispatch require-jquery.js:5385
elemData.handle.eventHandle
```

shim:

```
  archive: {
      deps: ["jquery", "strophe"],
      exports: "archive"
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You invoke a deferred obj and assign it to `q`, and then you assign the result of `listCollections` to `q`. These are two different and completely unrelated assignments. Just because you made `q` a deferred initially doesn't mean that the result from `listCollections` is now somehow `deferrable`.

```
    var q = $.Deferred();  // q is a deferred obj
    q = connection.archive.listCollections("user@server.lit"); // q is undefined
```

`listCollections` must return a deferred object for you to be able to call `done` on it.

Looking at the plugin code, it looks like `listCollections` doesn't return anything.

Instead, you must pass `listCollections` a callback function:

```
    var q = $.Deferred();     
    q = connection.archive.listCollections("user@server.lit", null, function(){
        console.log("DONE");
    });
```

Alternatively, you can make a wrapper function for `listCollections` that will return a deferred.

```
    function deferrableListCollections () {
        var q = $.Deferred();     
        connection.archive.listCollections("user@server.lit", null, function(){
            q.resolve() ;
        });
        return q;
    }
```

No you can call something similar to your original code:

```
    q = deferrableListCollections("user@server.lit");
    q.done(function(){
        console.log("DONE");
    });
```